# How to point all domain with ELB dns

Tags: dns, amazon-ec2, load-balance

In Aws I am creating A ELB(Elastic Load Balancer ) for handling load over instances . my question is in previous we are use single instance and add this instance with an elastic ip . with this elastic IP we are pointed a multiple domain and subdomain in our domain provide account (in siteground ). Now how I point all domain and subdomian with ELB . Our ELB name is LAMPLB-xxxxxx.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com

Answer (score 1):

If the domains are subdomains (e.g. mysite.example.com) then what you need in DNS is a `CNAME` record.  The target of the record will be the ELB hostname.

```
mysite IN CNAME elb-hostname....amazonaws.com.
```

If the site is not a subdomain, but instead is a zone apex (e.g. example.com itself) then a `CNAME` record will not work, here.  Instead, you need an `ALIAS` record, which requires that your DNS be hosted in Route 53.

Alias records were designed as a solution to what is otherwise a limitation of the way DNS works.  At the top (apex, root) of a given domain, it's not possible for a standards-compliant DNS server to return a different name, the way `CNAME` does for hosts within a domain.

Since Route 53 has "internal" knowledge of the current RRs for the ELB, it uses that information to answer queries directly.

> Route 53 responds to each request with one or more IP addresses for the load balancer

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html

Note that you *can* use `ALIAS` records at the subdomain level, too... but they are only *required* when you're not working with a subdomain.

Comment: As an addendum, if you want a free DNS provider that supports ALIAS records at the zone apex, check out [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/). You have the option to use it for DNS only and not as a CDN.

Comment: Cloudflare apparently calls it [CNAME Flattening](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169056-CNAME-Flattening-RFC-compliant-support-for-CNAME-at-the-root).  Note that this setup uses a back-end query to resolve the address, so it's still RFC compliant.  Assuming it does not cache responses from the back-end query for an improper length of time, this appears to be a viable alternative.